# Git permissions different from folder to folder?

Tags: git, ubuntu, permission-denied

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I want to pull in code from Github. I am able to do this successfully in /home/me/project. I added the repo via

```
git remote add origin git@github.com/XXXXXXX
```

and everything works fine when I pull code.

However, when I go to /var/www/vhosts/project I am still able to add the remote origin but when I try to pull the code I get the permission error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is different from one directory to the next?

** UPDATE **

Here is the log output after running: sudo GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git fetch

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: do you have write access to `/var/www/vhosts/project`? try with `ls -l`

Comment: Yes both directories have the same permissions: drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Try running `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git fetch`. That will show lots of information about what ssh is doing. In particular, you should see `Offering RSA public key` lines telling you what keys the ssh client is trying.

Comment: what is the exact command you run in both cases? Are you running it as `sudo` in `/var/www/vhosts/project`?

Comment: You're using sudo the second time; git uses root's keyfiles, not yours.

Comment: For the first case I run 'git pull origin master'. Same for second except I also have to use sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa

This leads me to believe that you are running the `git` commands with `sudo` in the `/var/www/vhosts/project`. When you do so, you are temporarily running programs as `root`. So Ubuntu is looking for ssh keys in root's home directory `/root/.ssh/`. This is why you are getting different responses from the GitHub server. Your root user does not have an SSH key configured for your GitHub account.

To fix the problem, you have several options:

1. Create an SSH key in `/root/.ssh/` and upload the public key to your GitHub account.
2. Copy your private key from `/home/me/.ssh/` to `/root/.ssh/`.
3. Change the permissions on the `/var/www/vhosts/project` directory so that you don't have to use `sudo` to run `git`.